Flutter map and polylines route
I am currently coding in flutter framework, and trying to get familiar with flutter_map, polylines and markers along with the route service. I have written the following code, but it keeps giving me an exception of
Error: Exception: No route data available in the API response.
Following is the code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<List<LatLng>>? route;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    route = fetchRoute(
      LatLng(28.58256157514347, 77.32420983539001),
      LatLng(28.518005096303668, 77.38189447010934),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter Map Example')),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<LatLng>>(
          future: route,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
            } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
              return Center(child: Text('No route data available'));
            } else {
              return FlutterMap(
                options: MapOptions(
                  initialCenter: LatLng(28.550283, 77.348052),
                  initialZoom: 12.0,
                ),
                children: [
                  TileLayer(
                    urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                    userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
                    maxZoom: 19.0,
                  ),
                  MarkerLayer(
                    markers: [
                      Marker(
                        point: LatLng(28.58256157514347, 77.32420983539001),
                        width: 80,
                        height: 80,
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.pin_drop,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Marker(
                        point: LatLng(28.518005096303668, 77.38189447010934),
                        width: 80,
                        height: 80,
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.pin_drop,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  PolylineLayer(
                    polylines: [
                      Polyline(
                        points: snapshot.data!,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        strokeWidth: 4.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<LatLng>> fetchRoute(LatLng start, LatLng end) async {
    final apiKey = 'API KEY'; // Replace with your API key
    final url = 'https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=$apiKey&start=${start.longitude},${start.latitude}&end=${end.longitude},${end.latitude}';

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      print('API Response: $data');

      if (data['routes'] != null && data['routes'].isNotEmpty) {
        final route = data['routes'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'] as List;
        print('Route Coordinates: $route');

        return route.map((point) => LatLng(point[1], point[0])).toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception('No route data available in the API response');
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load route. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
}

Please note that I used my own key from open route service. I tested it manually too and it is giving me data.
Any help would be appreciated

Okay, I understand what your problem is. I can't check what type of info you're sending, but you can try debugging your code. Also, in front of the line where you make a request, you can place a breakpoint in Visual Studio Code (VSC). When you click the button or make the request, the code will stop at that line. You can then see in the top bar what happens step by step and check the data you're sending and the type of response the service returns.
And I would like you to give me the service response information or take a screenshot so I can see what information you're sending
